# Image limits in Content builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, images, fileupload

I found that there is a limit on the size of the image (5 MB) in Content builder

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_supported_file_types.htm&type=5

But is there any limit on the number of images? Is it possible to upload many images - for example: 1 000 000 (or more) ?

There is no information about this in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

> **What is the limit to number of assets in a folder in Content Builder?**
>
> Shared folders have a limit of 5,000 assets. **There is no limit to the
> number of assets that can be stored in a local folder.**

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_content_builder_faqs.htm&type=5